# Is there a cell/mobile friendly site for Apple feedback?

Tags: iphone, safari, websites

I have previously used:

https://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone.html

To send feedback. I was shocked that this web form is not CSS formatted correctly on safari for iPhone. It’s so annoying to fill in a form designed for a desktop browser on your cell/mobile. I expected more from Apple (in 2020 no less!).

Anyone know of a mobile friendly version of this site?

Answer (score 2):

Apple recommends using their [Feedback Assistant native app](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting), but this requires installing a beta profile (on iOS, built into MacOS).

If you want a web form, and are willing to sign into your Apple ID, you can use the [Feedback Assistant web app](https://feedbackassistant.apple.com).